# Settings for current SBT 0.13 project, using new Play 2.2.0 build.sbt syntax

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.2

I would like to cause the following value to be used in a build.sbt file for Play 2.2.0, which uses sbt 0.13:

```
Defaults.defaultSettings ++ findbugsSettings ++ Seq(jacoco.settings:_*)
```

What should I assign the above value to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line you wrote could be assigned to settings argument of a Project in .scala file.

To use them in .sbt just write them in their own 2 lines.

```
jacoco.settings

findbugsSettings
```

defaults are there by default.

If you need to import anything in .sbt file do it at the top.

From [sbt doc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html):

> build.sbt defines a Seq[Setting[_]]; it's a list of Scala expressions, separated by blank lines, where each one becomes one element in the sequence. If you put Seq( in front of the .sbt file and ) at the end and replace the blank lines with commas, you'd be looking at the equivalent .scala code.